# Парсинг файла txt. Python 3.6

Tags: python

Есть файл с кучей емайл адресов, но некоторые из них написаны некорректно, то есть отсуствует @ или точка. Моя задача написать скрипт, который бы отфильтровывал все это безобразие. То есть, при условии, что на каждой строке располагается по одному емайлу, и на какой-то из строк есть некорректный адрес (без собачки или точки), то мне нужно эту строку перепрыгнуть и сразу начать со следующей.

Пока что пытаюсь сделать так:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        if '@' or '.' not in line:
            line_num += 1
```

То есть, если на строке с адресом нету собачки или точки, переменной line_number присваевается значение + 1 и это вроде как должно сказать программе начать проверять другую строку. Но не сработало. Как бы вы решили данную задачу?

Comment: `if '@' or '.' not in line:` работает как `if ('@') or ('.' not in line):` , а не как `if ('@' or '.') not in line:` скобки здесь я поставил для наглядного представления

Comment: К тому же, `if ('@' or '.') not in line:` работало бы просто как `if '@' not in line:`, потому что or в python работает так: `x or y` это `if x is false, then y, else x` https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: Вообще, если это не учебная задача по фильтрации содержимого текстового файла, надо сразу переходить к регулярным выражениям и выполнять полную валидацию адреса.

Comment: @mkkik регулярные выражения могут одновременно слишком разрешающими быть и слишком строгими (адреса, разрешённые стандартами и используемые на практике разнятся)¶ На практике, можно использовать regex для предварительной фильтрации и фактическую проверку проводить с помощью *посылки письма с одноразовой ссылкой.*

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '@' in line and '.' in line:
            # do something
```

По поводу предложений парсить регуляркой – https://habr.com/post/175375/.

Но если **очень**  хочется

```
import re


email_regexp = r"^[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+(?:\.[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)*(?:aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|[a-z][a-z])$"

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.match(email_regexp, line):
                # do something
```

Регулярка взята [отсюда](https://habr.com/post/55820/)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, посыл статьи следующий: нет смысла валидировать регуляркой, если валидный адрес может оказаться несуществующим, и это все равно вскроется при отправке ответа. Задача ТС отфильтровать заведомо невозможные адреса, коих может быть неограниченно много. Поэтому статья с кричащим заголовком, я думаю, тут неуместна.

Comment: @mkkik и типичная регулярка не менее успешно отсеивает неограниченно много заведомо возможных адресов

Answer (score 2):

```
line_num = 0
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '@' not in line or '.' not in line:
            line_num += 1
```

Comment: Это корректный email: `dsds.sds@dsd` ?

Comment: @AndrioSkur Исходя из поставленных требований - да :p

Comment: Хм. Да, по факту такой адрес пройдёт.