# Как записать N чисел в 1 строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Иван Васильевич пришел на рынок и решил купить два арбуза: один для себя, а другой для тещи. Понятно, что для себя нужно выбрать арбуз потяжелей, а для тещи полегче. Но вот незадача: арбузов слишком много и он не знает как же выбрать самый легкий и самый тяжелый арбуз? Помогите ему!

Входные данные
В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT задано одно число N – количество арбузов. **Вторая строка содержит N чисел, записанных через пробел.** Здесь каждое число – это масса соответствующего арбуза. Все числа натуральные и не превышают 30000.

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести два числа через пробел: массу арбуза, который Иван Васильевич купит теще и массу арбуза, который он купит себе.

Comment: Покажите что вы пробовали

Comment: Я еще не пробовал потомушто незнаю как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот начало кода:

```py
n = int(input('Количество арбузов'))
mas = [float(a) for a in input('Веса арбузов через пробел: ').split()]
```

получается что будет создан массив(mas) в котором в каждой новой ячейке будет вес арбуза

пример:

```py
>>>mas = [float(a) for a in input('Веса арбузов через пробел: ').split()]
Веса арбузов через пробел: 0.9 2.2 5.1 3.1 1 4.2
>>>print(mas)
[0.9, 2.2, 5.1, 3.1, 1.0, 4,2]
```

ну вы потом отсортируйте и возьмите последний элемент(mas[-1]) для Ивана а для тёщи предпоследний элемент(mas[-2])

```py
>>> mas = [4.1, 1.1, 0.9, 2.7]
>>> print(mas)
[4.1, 1.1, 0.9, 2.7]
>>> mas.sort()
>>> print(mas)
[0.9, 1.1, 2.7, 4.1]
```

Comment: Выходные данные В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести два числа через пробел: массу арбуза, который Иван Васильевич купит теще и массу арбуза, который он купит себе.

Comment: @S.Nick что?.....

Comment: вывести два числа

Comment: @S.Nick это подсказка а не полный ответ, ведь что бы научится нужно самому делать

Comment: Подсказки пишутся в комментариях

Comment: @S.Nick и ещё я ответил на его вопрос? - да

Comment: @S.Nick его вопрос был ```Как записать N чисел в 1 строке```

Comment: нет, вы не ответили на его вопрос.

Comment: Нет, он ответил!

Comment: @Денис спасибо, выручил

Comment: @Денис я дополнил ответ(поможет тебе немного)

Comment: @Денис если не трудно то можешь поставить что мой ответ полезный(просто какого то фига мне дали блокировку(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) и я не могу задать свой вопрос на форуме)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помог!

Comment: Серьезно? Искать максимум сортировкой?

Comment: можно и по другому, но это в 2 строчки и самый короткий метод(а обычным методом 4-5 строчек)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь банальный поиск максимума и минимума. Сортировка не нужна от слова совсем. Вот пример кода

```
filer=open("input.txt","r")
n=int(filer.readline())
numbers=[ float(x) for x in filer.readline().split()]
filer.close()
zmax=numbers[0]
zmin=numbers[0]

for i in range(n):
    if numbers[i]>zmax:
        zmax=numbers[i]
    if numbers[i]<zmin:
        zmin=numbers[i]

filer=open("output.txt","w")
out=str(zmin)+" "+str(zmax)
filer.write(out)
filer.close()
```

input.txt

```
10
1.2 2 0.4 2 3 4 8 2.1 1 3.2
```

output.txt

```
0.4 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Сплитом разделяете значения по ключу ( в вашем случае это пробел) - имеете несортированный массив. 
Сортируете любым удобным для вас способом. И array[0] это будет Васильича арбуз, а array[N-1] арбуз для любимой тещи

Comment: Ах да, Вам для начала нужно распарсить файл. 
Для этого как пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844308/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-txt-python-3-6

Comment: А можно показать, как ето будет виглядить в коде?